# Node JS API is responding very slowly

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

API of my webapp is responding very slowly. I checked and found that there is `hardly any query in slow query log`.

It seems there is some database connectivity bottleneck issue.

I checked mysql workbench client connection tab and found that:

`Total Connections: 892` (this was much higher but after db restart came down to this)

`Connection Limit: 640`

My sequelize db connection code is as follows:

```
'use strict'

const Sequelize = require('sequelize').Sequelize
const dbConfig = require('../config/database')
const logger = require('../helpers/logger').logger

let sequelize = new Sequelize(
  dbConfig.name,
  dbConfig.username,
  dbConfig.password,
  {
    host: dbConfig.host,
    port: dbConfig.port,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    define: {
      charset: 'utf8mb4',
    },
    pool: {
      max: dbConfig.poolMax,
      min: dbConfig.poolMin,
      acquire: dbConfig.poolAcquire,
      idle: dbConfig.poolIdle
    }
  }
)

sequelize.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    logger.info('[Sequelize] Connection Successful')
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    logger.error(err, '[Sequelize] [authenticate] Some Error Occurred')
  })

module.exports = sequelize
```

Where::

```
dbConfig.poolMin=0
dbConfig.poolMax=20
dbConfig.poolIdle=10000
dbConfig.poolAcquire=30000
```

I am struggling to find out the actual issue.[image]

Comment: Try to find out what's going on on your server. Is it pegged for CPU, IO? Your output also suggests that a lot of queries might be blocked by some other query

Comment: @Evert Yes, it looks like so. What can I do to unblock the queries ?

Comment: Try to find the query that's doing the blocking, and share it here.

Comment: @Evert CPU is at running at 25% max, Memory is running at 30% max

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST does not show any query as blocked, all the process are in SLEEP condition

Comment: Does "Total Connections" continue to rise?  If so, you should probably look at Connections per second.

Comment: What is the value of `long_query_time`?  It should be smaller than the default of 10 (seconds).  Set it to 1 globally.

Comment: Total connection continue to rise every passing second, long query time is currently set to 1 second